# not sure why join query is returning resultset longer than i'd expect, and taking long to execute

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join

I have reached an impasse with my knowledge regarding mysql joins, and the query I'm trying to execute is taking way too long... Although I'm only a short while into learning mysql on my own, I have put time into reading about the mechanics of indexes and joins, done many google searches and tried a few different query formats. To no avail, I need help please.

Firstly, I will say that my database is, at the moment, to be optimized for speed of select queries. I know I have a few too many indexes... my theory of learning mysql is to make a few too many indexes and examine what the mysql optimizer chooses for my purposes (determined by using explain) and then determine why it has chosen said index.

Anyhow, I have four tables: table1, table2, table3, table4...

table1.ID1 is the primary key, and other data in table1 might be divided into multiple content in table2.
table2.ID1 identifies every entry in table1 that is built upon content form table1
table2.ID2 is the primary key for table2
table3.ID2 identifies every entry in table3 that is built upon content form table2
table3.ID3 is the primary key for table3
table4.ID3 identifies every entry in table4 that is built upon content form table3

Not every entry in table1 has corresponding data in table2, and similarly table2 to table3, and table3 to table4.

What I need to do is retrieve the distinct values of ID2 that appear within a date range, and also only if the table2 content eventually appears in table4. The challenge I'm facing is that only table1 has a date column, and I need only entries that also appear in table4.

The following query takes approx 2 minutes.

```
select table2.ID2 from table1 
left join table2 on
table1.ID1 = table2.ID1
left join table3 on
table3.ID2 = table2.ID2 
left join table4 on
table4.ID3 = table3.ID3
where table1.Date between "2012-03-11" and "2012-03-18
```

by using explain with the above query I see no reason why it should take so long.

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys        | key      | key_len | ref                          | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1       | range | ...                  | Datekey  | 9       | NULL                         | 17528 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2       | ref   | ...                  | ID1key   | 8       | mydata.table1.POSTID         |     1 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table3       | ref   | ...                  | ID2key   | 8       | mydata.table2.SrcID          |    20 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table4       | ref   | ...                  | ID3key   | 8       | mydata.table3.ParsedID       |    10 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

I've replaced the names of possible keys with '...' as its not that important. In any case, a key is selected.

Moreover, the number of rows in the resultset in the query is much more than the purported matching 17528 rows in the explain resultset. How could it be more??

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried inner join with no luck. The way I interpret my query is a 4-way venn diagram, with very few number of rows with overlapping criteria, and further optimized by an index on the daterange.

I at least get the resultset that i want if I add 'distinct(table2.ID2)', but why am I otherwise getting a resultset much longer than what I'd expect, and why is it taking so long?

Sorry if any part of my question has been ambiguous, I'd be happy to clarify as needed.

Thanks,
Brian

EDIT:

All indexes refer to a BIGINT column, as I expect my database to get rather large and need quite a number of unique row identifiers... perhaps bigint is overkill and reducing the size of that column and/or the index would speed things up further.

Here's my final solution, based on the accepted answer below:

```
select ID2 from table2
where exists
    (select 1 from table1 r
    where table1.Date between "2012-03-11" and "2012-03-18" and table2.ID1 = table1.ID1
    )
and exists
    (select 1 from table3
    where exists 
        (select 1 from table4 where table4.ID3 = table3.ID3) 
    )
```

Additionally, I realized I was missing a multi-field index, associating table2.ID1 and table2.ID2... After adding this index, this statement returns in about 11 seconds, and returns approx 20,000 rows.

I think this is reasonable considering the number of rows in each of my tables
table1: ~480,000
table2: ~480,000
table3: ~6,000,000
table4: ~60,000,000

Does this sound efficient? I'll accept the answer after I get confirmation this is the best performance I should expect. I'm running on a Xeon 3GHz system with 3gb mem, ubuntu 12.04, mysql 5.5.24

Comment: I was going to edit my answer to expand further, but really it would be sooo much easier to answer this with some idea of what the data is and what you're trying to achieve rather than everything being table1, table2, etc... For one thing, you refer to this as a venn diagram, but it seems very much more like a tree structure.

Comment: as far as the data, what is the actual content I'm archiving is rather irrelevant I believe. All the columns that matter for this query are simple primary keys, which are bigints... I edited and added some info to my original post about the indexes, and I needed to add one multi-field index to best optimize this.

Comment: yes, you're right though, it is more of a tree than venn diagram, but i had read about joins as explained through venn diagrams and that's how I had thought of it. now it makes more sense knowing that it returns more than one row for each matching column value when a tree-like series of tables is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, your tables have multiple matches between them.  Say table1 matches 5 rows in table2 and 10 rows in table3.  Then you end up with 50 rows in the output.

So solve this, you need to limit your joins to one row per table.

One way is to use the in clause.  If you are using the joins for filtering, then you can use a where clause instead:

```
where table2.id1 in (select table1.id1 from table1)
```

The "in" prevents duplicates.

The other alternative is to pre-aggregate the queries in the joins by doing joins.

Mysql seems to prefer a slightly different construct for the where clause, from an optimization perspective:

```
where exists (select 1 from table1 where table1.id = table2.id)
```

Comment: Querying on a subquery like that is going to make things really slow, because the subquery will run for every potential row. If you're going to do that you should join to the subquery instead so it only runs once.

Comment: This is not how Mysql documents the use of subqueries (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html).  Could you please provide a reference for your statement?

Comment: That is admittedly a very confusing page of the mysql documentaion, which is already confusing at the best of times, but I believe you are misinterpretting it. To me that just says that it passes the match down to the subquery as an implicit where, which still means that the subquery is executed for every potential row, just more efficiently than it would be without that constraint.

Comment: It clearly says that it evaluates the subquery in its entirety, after evaluating the left hand argument.  However, it is not clear what happens afterwards, and the documentation does give a suggestion for a better performing version.  I re-edited the answer with this suggestion.

Comment: In fact, reading it again, I don't think the documentation is even saying that mysql makes that optimisation; it's just suggesting that you do it manually.

Comment: Note it says 'argument' not 'arguments'; it's not finding all the possible arguments and running the subquery against that, it's running the subquery against each argument. At least it reads that way to me, and the various tests I've tried in the past suggest this to be the case.

Comment: Oh, you may be right.  It is hard to believe that the optimizer could be that bad, but I don't have extensive experience with analyzing performance of mysql queries.  I guess the join method is better, although the "exists" with an index on the appropriate column should do a good job.  By the way, thanks for your comments . . . I learned something.

Comment: very helpful discussion.. yes the mysql manual reading is pretty dense and difficult to interpret at times. I think the "where exists (select 1 ... " is the correct path... I updated my original post with some additional info and an updated query that runs fairly efficiently as far as I can tell... can you confirm this is probably the best approach? Thanks!

Comment: accepted despite no further replies, it put me on the correct path.. see edits appended to OP